# How to reconnect with strophe via websocket to xmpp server?

Tags: websocket, xmpp, strophe

It's possible to reconnect websocket connection after page refresh?
Attach function works only with BOSH.
Request for password on every page refresh is such uncomfortable way.
Strophe can connect only with plain password so there is no way to pass password from database. 
Or is safe way to store plain password?

Comment: did you found a solution to this? I'm currently facing the same issue

Comment: No, i switched to BOSH